# FFmpeg - How to embed an EIA-608 caption stream into an mpeg2video VOB

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a CC track that I generated for a DVD stream using a self made script. I'd like to slipstream this Closed Captions track into an mpeg2video stream for compatibility with my TV's caption decoder. My struggle lies in the fact that I've only found info on how to transcode these tracks into formats such as SRT. Is there a way to do this in FFMPEG or is this a lost cause?